# install software whose certificate has expired

Tags: printer, certificate

So turns out for me to scan using my printer (it's a Samsung SCX-4100 Series, by the way), I have to install this software called SmartThru Office 2 (some UI Samsung made a while back). I tried opening the EXE installation file but my computer blocked the installation, saying its certificate was expired. Is there any way to install software if it's certificate expired?

Comment: You could put the clock back temporarily ...

Comment: that didn't work.